# Write To file with getResource

Tags: java, getresource

I use This methods to Write to a text file(use getResource()... to use in JAR file).
My files are in Classpath, 
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class JarWrite {

    public JarWrite(){
        writethis();
    }

    public void writethis(){

        try{
       InputStreamReader isReader=  new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("AllBookRecords.txt"));
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isReader);

      PrintWriter writer1=new PrintWriter(new File(this.getClass().getResource("Boutput.txt").getPath()));

      String Bs;
            while( (Bs=br.readLine()) != null ){                 
                    writer1.println(Bs);               
            }

            writer1.close();
            br.close();

        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){

        } catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new JarWrite();
    }    
    }
```

Comment: All `Thank You's` added to `Trash`.

Comment: What is the question? That is the Exception?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a Java program use files inside the .jar for read and write?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052311/how-can-a-java-program-use-files-inside-the-jar-for-read-and-write)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify resources from CLASSPATH. They are read only. Period.

See also: [*Java OutputStream equivalent to getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031671/605744).

Comment: @Sajjad-himorning: just use standard `FileWriter` and file system?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

```
public void writethis
```

to

```
public static void writethis
```

Comment: ... and that will not compile because in the first line there is a reference for `this.getClass()`