# Modifying a properties file inside a war

Tags: java, properties, architecture, war

I understand that a properties file cannot be modified inside a war ( I cannot write to it) . my war is essentially a java wrapper to make rest calls . so essentially , I make a POST call to the app , the app does its magic makes a few calls to different services and returns the data to me in a particular format . I am using apikey authentication to communicate with the application . I now want now design a private rest call to update some of these parameters incase we need to change the apikey at a later time .

so essentially the app will read everything off an properties file . I now understand that I  [cannot write to a properties file when it is packaged in a war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031248/java-outputstream-equivalent-to-getclass-getclassloader-getresourceasstream) and am in quite a pickle . I cannot use a database because I am not sure which env it will be deployed to and I need it to be self contained .

Any help on how I can get over this problem will be greatly appreciated .

Comment: Just externalize the property file, and make your app inside war read from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external property files as Sajan suggested. Or use  [Java Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html)